Levy's Upward theorem and bayes theorem application to a martingale.

Could some give me some hints on how to apply the 2 recommended theorems to this question.
I'm fairly stumped and ended up resorting to proving the martingale by brute force.

Let $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. It's not difficult (using Bayes's theorem) to show that $E[\xi| S_n]=M_n$, a computation you've probably already done.
But what you really want is $E[\xi|\mathcal F_n]=M_n$.
Using the Strong Law of Large Numbers (rather than the "upward" convergence theorem) you get $$
\lim_n \displaystyle{{S_n\over n}}=(\xi+3)/6,\qquad \hbox{a.s.},
$$
the point being that $\xi$ is (a.s.) a symmetric function of the $X_i$s. Now argue that $E[\xi|\mathcal F_n]$ is a symmetric function of $(X_1,
\ldots,X_n)$. That is, there is a symmetric function $f_n:\{0,1\}^n\to[0,1]$ such that $E[\xi|\mathcal F_n]=f_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Now think carefully about what form $f_n$ can take.
